# "He is/was the first man to go into space" vs. "he is/was the first man to have gone into space"

Tags: difference

Could you please tell me if there is any difference in meaning between the following sentences?

> Yuri Gagarin was a great astronaut and **he is the first to go** into space.
>
> Yuri Gagarin was a great astronaut and **he was the first to go** into space.
>
> Yuri Gagarin was a great astronaut and **he is the first to have gone** into space.
>
> Yuri Gagarin was a great astronaut and **he was the first to have gone** into space.

If there is no difference in meaning, are all of them natural and correct?

Comment: See [Which tense to use when referring to the first ever incident/achievement?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/157060) for the ***is / was*** part of your question. Or [Shouldn't it be “he was the most famous fighter to have ever lived”?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/165935) for the ***to go / to have gone*** part. In your exact context I'd say they're all equivalent, but consistency *(**was + was**)* and simplicity *(**to go**)* should probably be factors affecting your choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. Yuri Gagarin was a great astronaut and he is the first to go into space.
> 2. Yuri Gagarin was a great astronaut and he was the first to go into space.
> 3. Yuri Gagarin was a great astronaut and he is the first to have gone into space.
> 4. Yuri Gagarin was a great astronaut and he was the first to gone into space.

All of them need a comma before the coordinating conjunction.

#4 is ungrammatical:  to + past participle does not work

#1 has a mistake: the tenses shift from simple past to simple present.

#2 is correct English (with a comma)

> Yuri Gagarin was a great astronaut, and he was the first to go into
> space.
>
> Yuri Gagarin, the first man in space, was a great astronaut.
> (better)

#3 is acceptable because this usage of the perfect infinitive is correct.  It refers to an action at a time before that of the main verb.

Examples:

> She seems to have eaten all of the cookies.
>
> He must have worked all night on the project.
> (modal verbs omit to)
>
> Tommy pretended not to have eaten the cookies.

#3 adds importance to Gagarin's feat.  It makes it sound important to the current time.

> Yuri Gagarin, the first to have gone into space, was a great
> astronaut.